# A program to find length of string

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int string_length(char s[]);
main()
{
        char s[50];
        int l;
        printf("Enter the string\n");
        scanf("%s\n",s);
        l=strlen(s);
        printf("Length of string = %d\n",l);
}
int string_length(char s[])
{
        int i;
        i=0;
        while(s[i] != '\0')
                ++i;
                return i;

}
```

After compile it scan for two input values.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You did receive an answer in your previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685497/using-recursion-to-find-the-length-of-a-string-in-c - Why do you repaste that exact same question?

Answer (score 7):

Get rid of the newline in the `scanf`.

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

That should get this code to work.

But I am unable to understand why you wrote a function to compute string length if you had to use `strlen()`.

HTH,
Sriram.

Comment: If it solved your problem Jashid, you should mark this answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const size_t sillyStrlen(const char* text) {
  if (*text) {
    return sillyStrlen(text + 1) + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think adding '\0' meant that there is no limit for string.Right?

Comment: @Jashin: Your test for '\0' is the same as Jim's test (*text), both test for null.

Comment: Just posting the code for a homework question isn't a great way to help the OP learn.  You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937007/problem-with-recursion which had a great answer for a homework recursion problem.

Comment: You want to return a `size_t` instead of a `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `strlen` instead of your own `string_length` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy a book, see [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/427545)
2. Read about the language syntax
3. Learn how to use **pointers**
4. You've just learned how to write a `int strlen(char[])` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
   {
    char *str;
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("The size of the string is %d",strlen(str));
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```